# Golang azure devops pipelines rest api call to disable a pipeline

Tags: go, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am struggling with this issue.
I am trying to write a program in golang to access azure devops build pipelines, look for a specific pipeline and desable it.
I created a personal access token and i am able to authenticate without any issue. but when i run my code i get the following error:

`"message": "The request specifies pipeline ID 524 but the supplied pipeline has ID 0."`

The code i have looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

type Pipeline struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    // Include other relevant fields if needed
}

func main() {
    organization := "myorg"
    project := "project"
    pipelineID := 524
    email := "myemail"
    pat := "mypat"

    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://dev.azure.com/%s/%s/_apis/build/definitions/%d?api-version=6.1", organization, project, pipelineID)

    client := &http.Client{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to create request:", err)
        return
    }

    authString := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", email, pat)
    encodedAuth := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(authString))
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedAuth)

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to get pipeline:", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        fmt.Println("Failed to get pipeline, status code:", resp.StatusCode)
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to read response body:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Response body:", string(body))

    // Parse the response body to check if the pipeline is already disabled
    var pipeline Pipeline
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &pipeline)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to parse response body:", err)
        return
    }

    if pipeline.ID != pipelineID {
        fmt.Println("Pipeline ID mismatch. Expected:", pipelineID, "Actual:", pipeline.ID)
        return
    }

    // Disable the pipeline
    req, err = http.NewRequest("PUT", url, strings.NewReader(`{
        "enabled": false
    }`))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to create request:", err)
        return
    }

    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedAuth)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    resp, err = client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to disable pipeline:", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        fmt.Println("Failed to disable pipeline, status code:", resp.StatusCode)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Pipeline disabled successfully.")
}
```

The newRequest `GET` returns all the details of the pipeline and the response body shows the `"id": 524` but for some reason the api call seems to dont find it and returns a 0 instead.

i have been looking at my code over and over but i cannot see what i am doing wrong.

On the other side, i tried to perform the same action in postman, and even there the issue is the same.

Can please anyone help me to understand what i am doing wrong here?

Thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation: [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)

> It is recommended that you obtain the existing build definition by
> using GET, modify the build definition as necessary, and then submit
> the modified definition with PUT.

in this case, you have to update your `json` by the path: `options->enabled`
Here you can find the enabled property: [BuildOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#buildoption)

or you may try to send just this part:

```
{
  "id": 524,
  "options" :
  {
    "enabled": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. i tried the solution you said but i am still getting the same error. not matching ID